# Nix GLFW Haskell bindings missing library?

Tags: haskell, nix

I'm trying to compile a Haskell program (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-export)

However I'm running into the following error:

```
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /nix/store/f2730k4icw6biaaw3k81x853sch2ig8k-bindings-GLFW-3.2.1.1/lib/ghc-8.6.5/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.5/libHSbindings-GLFW-3.2.1.1-HsSdzRmGNYCJBRDKgdT43y-ghc8.6.5.so (/nix/store/wx1vk75bpdr65g6xwxbj4rw0pk04v5j3-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /nix/store/f2730k4icw6biaaw3k81x853sch2ig8k-bindings-GLFW-3.2.1.1/lib/ghc-8.6.5/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.5/libHSbindings-GLFW-3.2.1.1-HsSdzRmGNYCJBRDKgdT43y-ghc8.6.5.so))
cabal: repl failed for exe:xmonad from my-xmonad-0.2.0.0.
```

How could I resolve this dependency?

---

What I've tried:

- Adding the `bindings-GLFW` haskell package but this did not make any
  difference.
- Adding the `glibc` package via the following:

  ```
  #(myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) {}).overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
    #buildInputs = (oldAttrs.buildInputs or []) ++ [ pkgs.glibc ];
  #})
  ```

  This seems to give me another error of:

  ````
  nix build
  builder for '/nix/store/kp5m6kfwjfr4w59ypcnqqqn9812q6vpy-my-xmonad-0.2.0.0.drv'
  failed with exit code 1; last 10 log lines:
  /nix/store/gwwycf3w6cbj0gd2mpgblrdjc24f3cys-binutils-wrapper-2.31.1/bin/ld.gold
  No pkg-config found Using runghc version 8.6.5 found on system at:
  /nix/store/hg3na12737n7wws1kndxvs95ai88fgn8-ghc-8.6.5/bin/runghc
  Using strip version 2.31 found on system at:
  /nix/store/ajrrkivdfvp8dp4vdg5hp1h5hblmanc9-binutils-2.31.1/bin/strip
  Using tar found on system at:
  /nix/store/aawf0q16ql39w2gwv52qyjfzgbg5f22r-gnutar-1.32/bin/tar No
  uhc found
  *** abort because of serious configure-time warning from Cabal [1 built (1 failed), 0.0 MiB DL] error: build of
  '/nix/store/kp5m6kfwjfr4w59ypcnqqqn9812q6vpy-my-xmonad-0.2.0.0.drv'
  failed ```
  ````

---

My entire nix expression:

```
{
  nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
, compiler ? "ghc865"
, sources ? import ./nix/sources.nix
} :
let
  niv = import sources.nixpkgs {
    overlays = [
      (_ : _ : { niv = import sources.niv {}; })
    ] ;
    config = {};
  };
  pkgs = niv.pkgs;
  myHaskellPackages = pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.override {
    overrides = self: super: rec {
      gloss-export = pkgs.haskell.lib.dontCheck (import /home/chris/NewProjects/gloss-export/default.nix {});
    };

  };
in
(myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) {}).overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
  buildInputs = (oldAttrs.buildInputs or []) ++ [ pkgs.glibc ];
})
```